# Received child tax credit refund after owing federal taxes

Tags: united-states, income-tax, income-tax-refund, tax-credit

I filed my taxes (married filing jointly) in early February and owed $2,075 in taxes on AGI of $160,750. I have 2 children (ages 6 and 8) who I claim as dependents.

We were issued 6 monthly payments for the first half of the child tax credit from August-December 2021 for $462.00 each.

After paying the $2,075 owed after filing our 2021 taxes, I received a check for $2,775 from the feds a few days ago. I *think* this is the second half of the 2021 child tax credit, but why was I sent a check after *owing* money to the feds at filing?

Comment: Did you claim the child tax credit (which you believe is $2775?) on your tax return? It should be calculated on 1040 Schedule 8812, and flow onto line 28 of your form 1040 (i.e. it is added to the amount of taxes you have paid).